# Set more than one replica on a single host

Tags: mongodb

We are setting up a new mongo environment, migrating from an existing one. We currently have two shards, and we have three hosts for this (and an additional three, much smaller ones, as config servers).

Many examples show sharding as N mongod instances for a replica set, and then one RS for each shard.

If we want to deploy two shards to three hosts, this would mean that each host would have to run two mongod instances, one of which is a member of RS0, the other one being a member of RS1, and then RS0 would be used for the first shard, and RS1 for the second one.

1. I find some parts of the mongo documentation rather confusing, so I would like to confirm: is this assumption correct or not?
2. Does this make sense at all? Given that memory- and CPU-wise, this is sufficient, is there anything stupid about this setup?

Comment: What version of MongoDB server are you running and what outcomes are you hoping for with this configuration? With 2 shards backed by 3 member replica sets there are 6  `mongod` instances (not counting the config server `mongods`). That means each of your shard hosts should have a `mongod` for RS0 and RS1. Colocated instances will be competing for the same resources unless you are using `cgroups` or similar for resource management. Unless you have solid reasons for sharding (for example, plans to scale out) you may get better results out of your hardware using the three hosts as a replica set.

Comment: version is 3.6. and yes, the scaling part is exactly why we're doing this. thank you for at least the confirmation that the overall assumption is correct. do you have any experience how ugly running two mongods on one host can get - given somewhat evenly distributed workloads?

Comment: It's not necessarily ugly to run multiple `mongod` processes on the same host as long as you are careful about resource management and planning for failover, but for modern versions of MongoDB the general recommendation is to run a single `mongod` per environment. I assume you've done some testing to determine what works best for your workload.